Is the light reflected from an object the same as the incident light, or does the object emit a new beam?
When light reflects off an object, is the reflected beam composed of the same photons as the incident light, or does the object absorb the incoming light and then emit a new beam of light that is similar to the original?
Additionally, how can one prove that the reflected photon is or is not the same as the incident photon? I'm trying to understand whether the reflected light is simply redirected or if the object plays a role in re-emitting new photons.

Consider the photon a very localized wave in the EM field. When waves reflect off surfaces do we think of it as an old or new wave?

@PhysicsDave That would be a pulse, not to be confused with a photon.

@my2cts Yes a very small pulse, also called a quanta by many famous scientists.

@PhysicsDave A very small pulse is not a photon. It still only gives probabilities.

Since you  can't find a difference between the same photon reflected, and one absorbed and immediately re-emitted, it is better to say it is the same. Also after absorption the angle would be statistic and not deterministic.

So, if I understand correctly, we don't know whether it's a different photon or the same one, right?

@pie There is no observable difference between them. That doesn't necessarily mean that it's the same particle, but if it was absorbed and another particle emitted, the emitted particle exactly shares the properties of the absorbed particle, so they're functionally the same.

If there's a time delay, i.e. if some time passes "without light" between absorption and re-emission, then doesn't the photon cease to exist? Then wouldn't you say it's a different one? Perhaps continued existance or lack thereof is more relevant/useful than whether it's the same or different.

@PabloH Rather than ceasing to exist, you can think of it as bouncing around inside the material during that time.

There are observable differences.   Notably, application of a right-circular polarized light beam results in a left- circular polarized reflection.

It has different direction, and (if there's any Doppler broadening
due to motion of the reflector) different frequency.   That implies
different quantum numbers; it's a different photon.
Put another way, the reflection requires movement of charge in the
mirror/reflector, and that accelerated charge generates photons.
If you don't believe that the accelerated charge in the mirror is
causing the reflected light, where is the light going that
the mirror's accelerating charges ARE creating?
